# This is similar to mantic repository does not have a Release file, but the fix in there does not work for me in 23.10 ubuntu but it return this error

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager, 23.10, canonical

```
Hit:1 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com mantic InRelease                                           
Ign:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease                                          
Err:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu mantic Release   
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1003::3c9 80]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

in source.list file contains this following image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3ESg.png)

Comment: Have you tried disabling IPv6 or waiting for the servers to come back up?

Comment: I don't see mantic in archive yet ... try using the default repository.